# Where are Xamarin.Forms application properties stored on windows

Tags: wpf, xamarin.forms, uwp

Suppose I write

```
App.Current.Properties.Add("Crap", "123");
await App.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
```

Where is my crap saved, on disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties are saved in Xamarin with

```
const string PropertyStoreFile = "PropertyStore.forms";
...
var stream = IsolatedStorageFileStream(PropertyStoreFile, FileMode.Create, isoStore)
```

[Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF/Deserializer.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF/Deserializer.cs)

`IsolatedStorage` is a way for an application to store data that persists after closing, without having to specify where on disk it is saved. To find where yours is saved, go to `C:\Users\$USER$\AppData\Local\IsolatedStorage` and search for a files named `PropertyStore.forms`. It should be one of the results.

Answer (score -1):

In Xamarin form because you project is a cross platform project you cant find one place on your disk for each platform is created by your compiler for example, in windows executable form you can put your Key/Value variable in multi different destination, Registry, App config, … or in android executable form, you can put your Key/Value on service that is provided by android OS and called "Preferences".
finally, where your Key/Value variables are saved depend on which platform you run your code.

if you want more detail, I suggest you watch this link https://github.com/aritchie/settings/tree/master/Acr.Settings/Platforms .
this link provide interface for store Key/Value Pair variable and implement in 4 different kind of OS that you prefer to run you project on it.
I supposed you need to understand how this is happen in UWP, because you tagged it. In this platform you can search for ApplicationDataContainer.
if you want to find out how this happen and where values saved on disk in android OS, you can watch this link that is provided by Microsoft docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android