# How to access application properties in .NET MAUI?

Tags: .net, maui

I'm migrating an Android/iOS Xamarin.Forms application to .NET MAUI. In old version of the application I used `Application.Properties` to store some information. Now I can't use it, becuase it is marked with `ObsoleteAttribute` with `IsError` property set to true, so I get compilation error. I get an information, that I should use `Microsoft.Maui.Storage.Preferences` instead and that's what I did. The problem is, I have to move Properties to Preferences somehow after the application update. And I have no idea how I can access those properties. I was trying to ignore ObsoleteAttribute, but solutions like adding `#pragma warning disable` directive work only with warnings, not with compilation errors. Also I tried to access those properties via reflection, but I get `NotSupportedException` with message "Properties API is obsolete, use Microsoft.Maui.Storage.Preferences instead". Is there any way to disable this compilation error, or access those properties in some other way? Thank you for all ideas in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are Xamarin.Forms application properties stored on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66596440/where-are-xamarin-forms-application-properties-stored-on-windows)

Comment: This probably would answer my question if I was writing application for Windows. But I write application for Android and iOS, sorry for not mentionig this. I'll update my question.

Comment: The code is identical for all platforms, only the path varies.

Answer (score 0):

### Properties API is obsolete, use Microsoft.Maui.Storage.Preferences instead.

### Set preferences

Preferences are set by calling the Preferences.Set method, providing the key and value:

```
// Set a string value:
Preferences.Default.Set("first_name", "John");

// Set an numerical value:
Preferences.Default.Set("age", 28);

// Set a boolean value:
Preferences.Default.Set("has_pets", true);
```

### Get preferences

To retrieve a value from preferences, you pass the key of the preference, followed by the default value when the key doesn't exist:

```
string firstName = Preferences.Default.Get("first_name", "Unknown");
int age = Preferences.Default.Get("age", -1);
bool hasPets = Preferences.Default.Get("has_pets", false);
```

### Remove one or all keys

```
Preferences.Default.Remove("first_name");
            Or
Preferences.Default.Clear();
```

[Click here for more detail from .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=windows)

Comment: This does not answer the question, it was about how to migrate the properties from xamaring to maui (my old app was in xamarin and I didn't want the data to be forgotten after upgrading to maui). Please, see my own answer I've just marked accepted.

Answer (score -1):

Getting the similar issue while creating .NET MAUI application.

Comment: This is not an answer... If you're still experiancing this, follow this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/issues/1690. Hopefully we will get some info in the nearest future